# How can i check if a Intent was created

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to check at the beginning of my App if an `Intent` exists. So when I launch it some details are displayed. I can then switch to a different class to edit those details. Now if i switch back to my Main class I want the details to be replaced with the ones I just edited. I hope you guys can help me out and hopefully you understand my question.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

     if (getIntent()!= null) {
         Intent myintent2 = getIntent();
         ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
         buffer = myintent2.getStringArrayListExtra("Interest_items");
         for (int f = 0; f < buffer.size(); f++) {
             Interests.add(buffer.get(f));
         }
     } else {
         Interests.add("Cycling");
         Interests.add("Swimming");
         Interests.add ("Running");
     }
}
```

Comment: need to add Bundle for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `boolean` .

First define a `boolean` as `false` above `onCreate` part

Then change its value to `true` in the `intent` body

Now you can write an `if` control sentence to find that the desired `intent` has already executed or not

Another way is correcting your code like this:

```
if (getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Interest_items"))!= null)
```

Comment: Hi i tried that but my clicked variable is always false, i defined it outside the onCreate.

Comment: I have used this method many times. please send your code so that I may help you to find the problem.

Comment: Ok I tried checking for the Intent extras and that worked for me thanks!

Comment: I am glad to hear that. So please accept my answer as correct one. Thanks.